# How to have node property within a regex query?

Tags: regex, cypher

Say I have a node with a property like this:

```sql
create (test {path: 'cat/dog/mouse/last'} )
```

How should I use regex to trim the `/last` in the property? I am thinking about using

```sql
match (n {path: "cat/dog/mouse/last"}) 
set n.section =~ `regex-search-using-n.path-to-match-'cat/dog/mouse'-only`
return n.section
```

How should I do that?

- There is [`WITH`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/) clause and I guess we can use it with the [`replace()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/string/#functions-replace) function. But how do I put regex in its syntax (`replace(original, search, replace)`)?
- There is [regex in `WHERE`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#query-where-regex) clause, but it doesn't say about using node property in the regex.

So far my quick hack is to [`split()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/string/#functions-split) the string to a [list](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-lists-general) and select only the elements from the start to the next-to-last element:

```sql
match (n) 
set n.section=split(n.path,'/')[0..-1] 
return properties(n)
```

But I want to have a more canonical answer.

Comment: The regex to match something starting with `first` would be `^first(?=/|$)` meaning *starting with "first" only if it's followed by a slash or ending as is*. [You can test it here](https://regex101.com/r/xGDtwT/1) (the slash is escaped because it's already the pattern delimitor before the flags). I don't know what would be the syntax in *Cypher* as I don't know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this.

```
match (n) 
set n.section = apoc.text.replace(s.path, "(/\\w+)$", '')
return n
```